# Getting permutation for reactive streams

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have two reactive streams which should work asynchronously. As a result I should call `foo()` function which will take two arguments and would be called with all possible permutations of elements from two initial reactive streams. 
And it should fail everything in case of any exception happened during whole process. 
What is the best way to implement this by using reactor-core?

Example:

```
    String[] aInitial = {"a","b","c"};
    String[] bInitial = {"0","1"};

    Flux<String> fluxA = Flux.fromArray(aInitial);
    Flux<String> fluxB = Flux.fromArray(bInitial);

    ...

    private void foo(String a, String b){
        System.out.println(a + ", " + b); 
    }
```

Expected result (order doesn't matter):

> a, 0
>   a, 1
>   b, 0
>   b, 1
>   c, 0
>   c, 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of invoking the action (in your case the `System.out.println`) in the method doing the transformation, split it up into one function that combines elements from both, and another that actions that data.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] aInitial = {"a", "b", "c"};
    String[] bInitial = {"0", "1"};

    Flux<String> fluxA = Flux.fromArray(aInitial);
    Flux<String> fluxB = Flux.fromArray(bInitial);

    fluxA
            .flatMap(input1 -> fluxB.map(input2 -> foo(input1, input2)))
            .doOnNext(System.out::println)
            .blockLast();
}

private static String foo(String a, String b) {
    return a + ", " + b;
}
```

As you can see we iterate over the first flux, and use the second flux to create a nested loop of sorts.

Note that this won't work for hot fluxes, only cold fluxes will work here as we need to resubscribe to the second flux for every element that emits from the first one.

Comment: to avoid the re-subscription, provided you have a guarantee that one of the Flux is finite and would not blow up memory, you can use a common `.replay()` version of that Flux in the `flatMap`. Or `replay(Duration)` if you want to be more secured against memory pressure

Comment: I was thinking of collecting into a List, but `replay` is definitely a lot better.