# how to do a nested iteration of two flux in a single reactive stream

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor, java-17

I am getting an object `School` from an API, the resultant object contains two lists eg: `List<Student>`
and `List<Teacher>`, the elements of two lists has to be per-mutated as arguments to a method in a reactive way.

```
return schoolService.getSchool(1234)
.flatMap(schoolData -> Flux.zip(schoolData.getTeacher,schoolData.getStudent))
.map(zippedData -> getCountOfStudentsInCourse(zippedData.getT1()
,zippedData.getT2()));
```

**ps : The syntax is wrong. But to give some context I tried to wrap in the above code.**

1. `schoolService.getSchool` returns a school object.
2. school object contains a list of teachers and a list of students data.
3. I want to iterate each combination of a teacher and a student and pass to `getCountOfStudentsInCourse` method.
4. `getCountOfStudentsInCourse`  in turn returns a Flux<CourseData> after iterating every combination of a student and teacher.
5. the above operation should happen in a single stream

please suggest with some examples. thanks

Comment: Does this solve your question? [Getting permutation for reactive streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54565433/getting-permutation-for-reactive-streams). Essentially, you do something like `teachers.flatMap(teacher -> students.map(student -> getCountOfStudentsInCourse(teacher, student))` (so for each teacher you go through the entire students flux to get each permutation).

Comment: in the above example we have two flux declared. In my case, I have as a part of a previous call (as in : in single stream)

Comment: I don't think the previous call really matters though? From your code, it seems that both `schoolData.getTeacher` and `schoolData.getStudent` return a `Publisher`. So I assume you can do `schoolData.getTeacher.flatMap(teacher -> schoolData.getStudent.map(student -> getCountOfStudentsInCourse(teacher, student)))`